# pandas dataframe minus numpy series returns unusual DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a numpy Series object `y_train` with shape `(47,)` and a pandas DataFrame object `x_train.dot(theta)` with shape `(47, 1)`. However, `y_train-x_train.dot(theta)` returns a DataFrame object with shape `(47,48)`. What has happened?

```
y_train.head()
```

```
0    0.475747
1   -0.084074
2    0.228626
3   -0.867025
4    1.595389
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

```
x_train.dot(theta).head()
```

```
    0
0   0.0
1   0.0
2   0.0
3   0.0
4   0.0
```

```
(y_train-x_train.dot(theta)).head()
```

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46
0   0.475747    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   0.475747    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   0.475747    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   0.475747    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   0.475747    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5 rows × 47 columns
```

Comment: Can you put in the code to generate x_train and y_train please?

Comment: @Gracie This is the alignment problem, you need to subtract on `axis=0` to get the proper alignment check `x_train.dot(theta).sub(y_train, axis=0)` or `x_train.dot(theta) - y_train.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)`